# How to pass multiple string parameter in GraphQl query using apollo client

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, swift4.2

How can I create query with multiple string parameters. I have used apollo client and created query as follow. But xcode didnot allow to build.

```
mutation changePassword($oldPass: String, $newPass: String) {
    changePassword(old_password: $oldPass, new_password: $newPass) {      
    }
}
```

Comment: this is what code inside `gql` tag or `.gql` file should be like: 
``` mutation ($oldPass: String, $newPass: String) {
 changePassword(old_password: $oldPass, new_password: $newPass) {

   }
  }``` what error are you getting?

Comment: @kcsujeet yes it is the code of .graphql file in xcode. Due to that the auto generated file is not generating.

Comment: in your question you're using your mutation name `changePassword` twice. once try not using it after `mutation`. also can you update your question with your schema, resolvers ,your mutation call code?

Comment: I have change the mutation to name as follow but still facing same issue.
mutation PasswordChange($oldPass: String, $newPass: String) {
    changePassword(old_password: $oldPass, new_password: $newPass) {
        
    }
}

Comment: remove `PasswordChange` and try again with just `mutation { ... ` if your mutation name is `changePassword`. and please update your question with your schema, resolvers ,your mutation call code otherwise it'll be difficult to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the `input` key

```
mutation changePassword($oldPass: String, $newPass: String) {
    changePassword(input: {old_password: $oldPass, new_password: $newPass}) {      
    }
}
```

also, it will be helpful if you post the whole mutation code, one example could be:

```js
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import client from '../client';

function ChangePassword(parameters){
  return client.mutate({
    mutation: gql `
       mutation changePassword($oldPass: String!, $newPass: String){
         changePassword(input: {old_password: $oldPass, password: $newPass}){
           user {
             email
             firstName
             lastName
           }
         }
       }
    `,
    variables: {
      oldPass: parameters.oldPass,
      newPass: parameters.newPass,
    }
  })
};

export default ChangePassword;
```

where `user` is your payload

Comment: I have create the helper class actually, I just need to write that much to create whole mutation. After that I have found that we need to create a model to pass the multiple string. Thanks for you help though. Appreciated.